# Find all generators of $\langle a\rangle , \langle b\rangle,$ and $\langle c\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

Suppose that $\langle a\rangle , \langle b\rangle,$ and $\langle c\rangle$ are cyclic groups of orders $6, 8,$ and $20,$ respectively.

Find all generators of $\langle a\rangle , \langle b\rangle,$ and $\langle c\rangle$.

Comment: Angela, you have posted four questions today which are very like homework questions and which none of them you have tried to show any effort. Could you tell us what you think, what you know, etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at $\langle a\rangle$ which is a cyclic group of order $6$. Hence, $\langle a\rangle = \{a^0 = e, a^1, a^2 \cdots a^5\}$, by the definition of $\langle a\rangle$, where $|\langle a \rangle| = 6$.

Now, the elements of this group that are also generators of the group $\langle a \rangle$ are those elements $a^m$, where $m$ is an integer, $0\lt m \lt 6$, such that $\gcd(m, 6) = 1$. In this case, that would be only those $a^m$, where $m \in \{1, 5\}$: we already know $a^1 = a$ is a generator, but $a^5$ generates $\langle a\rangle$ as well.

Can you generalize this for a cyclic group of order $n$? You can apply this, then, in the same manner, to $\langle b\rangle$ and $\langle c\rangle$.

Comment: Needs a UV~TU~+1

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: If $G=\langle z\rangle$ is a cyclic group of order $n,$ say, then you know that the elements of $G$ are (in multiplicative notation) $1,z,z^2,...,z^{n-1}.$ For which $k\in\{0,1,2,...,n-1\}$ does $z^k$ have order $n$?